# what is the difference between who vs who,?

Tags: punctuation, relative-clauses

> In this game, the player, who keeps a cool head, wins.

or

> In this game, the player who keeps a cool head wins.

when to use comma before who and when not to use comma before who?

Comment: To help with readability, there should probably be a comma before "wins" in both sentences. It's not a "required" comma but it can help the reader by showing them that a pause is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sentences

> In this game, the player, who keeps a cool head, wins.
>   *emphasis is on keeping a cool head*
>
> In this game, the player who keeps a cool head, wins.
>   *emphasis is on player*
>
> In this game, the player who keeps a cool head wins.
>   *emphasis is on wins*

**Who keeps a cool head** is a subordinate clause modifying **player**, so being offset by commas is appropriate but not necessary.

**In this game** as the initial phrase, using a comma is appropriate.

The main gist of the sentence

> The player ... wins

is the independent clause.

Also appropriate might be

> In this game, whoever keeps a cool head wins.

Answer (score 0):

> In this game, the player, who keeps a cool head, wins.

The sentence means `In this game, the player wins`.  The `who keeps a cool head` is parenthetical and is extra information telling you that the player referred to keeps a cool head.

> In this game, the player who keeps a cool head, wins.

This means that all players who keep cool heads will win.